# ContentResolver usage

Tags: android-contentresolver

I am new to andriod domain and is in learning phase. I got couple of queries:

Do we have single ContentResolver object per app? 
Is it a singleton object? 
Who manages this object lifecycle?
If it's singleton, how does it handles multiple request of querying a ContentProvider?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Alex Lockwood's Blog -
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html

> **What is the Content Resolver?**
>
> The Content Resolver is the single, global instance in your
>   application that provides access to your (and other applications')
>   content providers. The Content Resolver behaves exactly as its name
>   implies: it accepts requests from clients, and resolves these requests
>   by directing them to the content provider with a distinct authority.
>   To do this, the Content Resolver stores a mapping from authorities to
>   Content Providers. This design is important, as it allows a simple and
>   secure means of accessing other applications' Content Providers.
>
> The Content Resolver includes the CRUD (create, read, update, delete)
>   methods corresponding to the abstract methods (insert, delete, query,
>   update) in the Content Provider class. The Content Resolver does not
>   know the implementation of the Content Providers it is interacting
>   with (nor does it need to know); each method is passed an URI that
>   specifies the Content Provider to interact with.
>
> **What is a Content Provider?**
>
> Whereas the Content Resolver provides an abstraction from the
>   application's Content Providers, Content Providers provides an
>   abstraction from the underlying data source (i.e. a SQLite database).
>   They provide mechanisms for defining data security (i.e. by enforcing
>   read/write permissions) and offer a standard interface that connects
>   data in one process with code running in another process.
>
> Content Providers provide an interface for publishing and consuming
>   data, based around a simple URI addressing model using the content://
>   schema. They enable you to decouble your application layers from the
>   underlying data layers, making your application data-source agnostic
>   by abstracting the underlying data source.
>
> **The Life of a Query**
>
> So what exactly is the step-by-step process behind a simple query? As
>   described above, when you query data from your database via the
>   content provider, you don't communicate with the provider directly.
>   Instead, you use the Content Resolver object to communicate with the
>   provider. The specific sequence of events that occurs when a query is
>   made is given below:
>
> - A call to `getContentResolver().query(Uri, String, String, String,    String)` is made. The call invokes the Content Resolver's query
>     method, not the `ContentProvider's`.
> - When the `query` method is invoked, the Content Resolver parses the `uri`    argument and extracts its authority.
> - The Content Resolver directs the request to the content provider    registered with the (unique) authority. This is done by calling the
>     Content Provider's `query` method.
> - When the `Content Provider's query` method is invoked, the query is    performed and a Cursor is returned (or an exception is thrown). The
>     resulting behavior depends entirely on the Content Provider's
>     implementation.