# Retrieve photo from contact android

Tags: java, android, photo, contacts

I used this code to retrieve a photo from one contact:

```
private Uri getPhotoUri(String idContact) {
        try {
            Cursor cur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + idContact + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                    null);
            if (cur != null) {
                if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return null; // no photo
                }
            } else {
                return null; // error in cursor process
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long
                .parseLong(idContact));
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }
```

So, the problem is that with this code I can retrieve a photo with low resolution. 
How can i do to get a better photo?

Maybe I am not supposed to use CONTENT_DIRECTORY.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works pretty well to get a high-res photo:

```
 Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
 InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, my_contact_Uri, true);
 BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
 Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
 buf.close();
 return my_btmp;
```

Also, just fyi, high-res contact photos didn't exist before API 14, so if you're running it on a AVD/Device with API 13 or less, you can't get a high-res photo.

Look at this question: [Get high-res contact photo as bitmap below API level 14 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671814/get-high-res-contact-photo-as-bitmap-below-api-level-14-android) for more info.

Comment: What is cr in the second line?

Comment: A ContentResolver object, used to provide more info on the account. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355870/contentresolver-usage